# Android ListView OnTouchListener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I created a custom listview inside fragment. Now I want to swipe left to right. I created a listener class for that. But listener not working for me.

Here is the listener class:

```
public class SwipeDetector implements OnTouchListener {

public static enum Action {
    LR, // Left to Right
    RL, // Right to Left
    TB, // Top to bottom
    BT, // Bottom to Top
    None // when no action was detected
}

private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private static final int HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 40;
private static final int VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

public boolean swipeDetected() {
    return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
}

public Action getAction() {
    return mSwipeDetected;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
            return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // horizontal swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                    return true;
                }
            } else 

            // vertical swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaY) > VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // top or down
                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                    return false;
                }
                if (deltaY > 0) {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                    return false;
                }
            } 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

And here is the Fragment:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Button addItem;
List<String> Testing;
ArrayAdapter<String> productAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // addChildFragOne();
    // addChildFragTwo();
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
    ListView productsList = (ListView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Testing = new ArrayList<String>();
    Testing.add("Hey");
    Testing.add("Hey");
    Testing.add("Hey");
    Testing.add("Hey");
    productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.product_item, R.id.textView2, Testing);
    productsList.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    addItem = (Button) RootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    addItem.setOnClickListener(this);

    final SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();

    productsList.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
    productsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()) {
                // do the onSwipe action
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Text!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Testing.remove(position);
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // do the onItemClick action
            }
        }
    });

    return RootView;

}


}
```

Why OnTouchListener not working? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe onTouch is conflicing with OnItemClickListener. So you can try by only use onTouch to holder both of swipe and item click

Answer (score -1):

your `setOnItemClickListener` is conflicing with `OnTouchListener`. In runtime you only can use one, so in your case i think you should use OnTouchListener  instea of setOnItemClickListener (not set setOnItemClickListener ).

Example code you can read here [use OnTouchListener instea of ItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563141/android-listview-using-onitemclick-and-ontouch)

Comment: Then how can I get the position of the list item?

Comment: @MohammadRajob you can try this: int itemPosition = listView.pointToPositon(MotionEvent .getX(), MotionEvent .getY());